Should I put my resume on GitHub?
A simple twist on the usual 'should I put my Github on my resume ?': Should I put my resume on GitHub ?
I have a LateX formatted document, that I could easily put on Github. It doesn't really have more or less information than what is available on my Linked-in page. The only downside I would see would be putting my personal contact outside in the open. But maybe this is a positive thing when one try to get hired ?
Is there a given answer to this ? or some pitfalls to avoid ?

What is the goal you are trying to accomplish by having your resume on Github?

Risk versus reward. The reward is a job. The risk is personal information that would need to be on the resume to make it useful (IMHO). Do you feel that it is worth it?

I foresee Hiring Manager/Recruiter engagement = 0 and Scammer/Hacker engagement = 100.

A resume should change often. GitHub is a place to store information that doesn't change that much, and that information should be coalescing into a stable form.

@joeqwerty His linked-in activity is enough for that. An online resume wouldn't add much. I swear that the person who built linked in is secretly a hacker who liked social engineering attacks, but is lazy. So created a website where people would voluntarily put all of the information on one site that would allow him create an attack vector for arbitrary companies with little to no effort.

Of course there is no "given answer" to this.
The Internet is half a century old. Putting personal information, including resumes, in it is nothing new. Glorified though it is, Github is just another website in the Internet. Only you can judge how much of yourself you are comfortable with sharing and balance that with the potential benefits.
If your activity on such website is low or on low visibility projects, then it is about as useful as pinning it to a cactus in the Saara desert. Well, maybe crawlers will find it useful...
